# php mysql adding values to array based on IF statements

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Using Joomla, having issues trying to build a mySQL query based on URL arguments.  The code I have looks like this:

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $hpprice = JRequest::getVar('hprice');
    $lprice = JRequest::getVar('lprice');
    $city = JRequest::getVar('city');
    $zip = JRequest::getVar('zip');
    $bdrms = JRequest::getVar('bdrms');
    $bths = JRequest::getVar('bths');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " WHERE 1=1";
    $clauses = array();
    if ($zip != null) {
        $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTZIP') . " = " . $db->quote($zip);
    }
    if ($city != null) {
        $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTCITY') . " = '" . $db->quote($city) . "'";
    }
    if ($bdrms != null){
        $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTBDRMS')." >= ".$db->quote($bdrms);
    }
    if ($bths != null){
        $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTBATHS') . " >= " . $db->quote($bths);
    }
    if ($lprice != null){
        $clauses[] = $db->nameQuote('MSTLISTPRC') . " BETWEEN " . $db->quote($lprice) . " AND " . $db->quote($hprice);
    } 

    $query .= implode(" AND ", $clauses);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();
    return $table;
```

So, as you can see it, adds arguments to the mySQL query based on whether or not arugments exist in the URL.  What I can't wrap my head around is building the array and imploding it.

Whenever I put an argument in the URL, all the table items populate.  When I try to pass an argument, it comes up null.  You can see this in action [here](http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=list).  If you add another argument like `zip` to the URL, everything comes up `NULL`.

Comment: did you check the query that's built before you try to execute it, e.g. `echo $query;`)? You're simply assuming that this code is building the query properly.

Comment: `$query . = ' and ' . implode(...)`

Comment: I just added the `and` to the end of the original `$query` statement. I'm guessing the `nameQuote` is what's adding the quotes.  Is there another function I can use to still pull that info?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, it will only add backticks around the field names. Update the question with the final query text, it's impossible to see from the comments because they mess with the backticks.

Comment: Was missing the `;` at the end of the query statement.  @Marc B, you did that on purpose, didn't you? ;)

Comment: Ok, I tried to run the statement produced in the console, and it didn't like the backticks.  Is there something I can use besides `nameQuote()` and doesn't put quotes or ticks around everything?

Comment: YOu should alway use nameQuote when you have names andyou should always use quote when you have string values.

Why are you not just using where()?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this `" WHERE 1=1"`.try to change this to this-`" WHERE 1=1 "`.
Because the final query will be appended to this and you'll not get the desire result.For  confirmation also `echo $query` see if it's a correct query.one more thing is `'" . $db->quote($city) . "'"`.remove `''` as you are already adding this by a function.

//Update:

Better to use [where](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJDatabaseQuery/where) method

Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Used a different solution.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is diffent than your previous question.

$query->select('*");
$query->from($db->nameQuote('#__mls'));

```
 $query->where('1 = 1', AND);
if ($zip != null)
{
  $query->where (.$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = ".$db->quote($zip)); 
}
if ($city != null) 
{ 
   $query->where($db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." = '".$db->quote($city)); 
} 

Etc
```

There is no need for you to build any array; that it the whole point of having a databasequery api.

Answer (score 0):

Final script ended up looking like this:

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $hprice = JRequest::getVar('hprice');
    $lprice = JRequest::getVar('lprice');
    $city = JRequest::getVar('city');
    $zip = JRequest::getVar('zip');
    $bdrms = JRequest::getVar('bdrms');
    $bths = JRequest::getVar('bths');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " WHERE 1=1 AND ";
    $clauses = array();
    if ($zip != null) {
        $clauses[] = "MSTZIP = " . $zip;
    }
    if ($city != null) {
        $clauses[] = "MSTCITY = " . $db->quote($city);
    }
    if ($bdrms != null){
        $clauses[] = "MSTBDRMS >= " . $bdrms;
    }
    if ($bths != null){
        $clauses[] = "MSTBATHS >= " . $bths;
    }
    if ($lprice != null){
        $clauses[] = "MSTLISTPRC BETWEEN " . $lprice . " AND " . $hprice;
    } 

    $query .= implode(" AND ", $clauses) . ";";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();
    return $table;
```

I ended up getting rid of `nameQuote` and `quote` except where needed/applicable.  The script model I was working off of was from some tutorial.  It worked for what I was doing previously, but not now for some reason.  Last step would be to make the initial `AND` conditional, but that shouldn't take much.  At least the framework is there now.  Thanks to all who helped.